# SQL spatial STIntersection spatial Index

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, indexing, spatial

Im trying to split polylines by points which have a small buffer around them.  Currently i have over 370,000 lines and 320,000 nodes and the query is running really slowly (ive left it for 3 days and it still hasnt completed).  I have tried forcing a spatial index using with (Index(SI_tempPD)) but i get the following error:

"The query processor could not produce a query plan for a query with a spatial index hint.  Reason: Could not find required binary spatial method in a condition.  Try removing the index hints or removing SET FORCEPLAN."

below is the snippet of code that im trying to run when i get the error:

```html
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TempLines (
     [linenum]
    ,[ogr_geometry]
    )
  SELECT lines.[linenum]
     ,lines.[ogr_geometry].STDifference(points.[ogr_geometry].STBuffer(0.005)) AS ogr_geometry 
  FROM dbo.TemplineData AS lines with(Index(SI_tempPD)) INNER JOIN dbo.[TemplineNodes] AS points
  ON lines.[ogr_geometry].STIntersection(points.[ogr_geometry]).STDistance(points.[ogr_geometry]) < 1
  WHERE (lines.[linenum] <> points.[linenum])
 END
```

is there anyway i can speed up the query? (I also have a clustered primary key)
the execution plan shows that a filter takes up 36% of the cost and the insert takes up 64%

any help would be greatly appreciated!

(im using SQL Server 2008  (SQL server Management studio 10.50.1600.1))

Comment: "Im trying to split polylines by points which have a small buffer around them." I don't understand what you're trying to do. I get that you have lines and points. In non-query terms, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What does your table and spatial index look like?

Comment: Cross-posted as https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/133215/115